# Reg ex for selecting and replacing a numeric value in a line that contains a specific pattern of string

Tags: regex, nedit

I have the following lines (using nedit)

R1_1 vsp vsp/1 23

R2_1 vsp/2 vsp/3 30

R3_2 vsp/3 vsp/4 50

R3_2 v2 v1 50

C1 vsp/1 vsp 60

I want to just replace the numbers with number*0 for the lines that start with **R** and contain the string **vsp**. I want the following in the above example

R1_1 vsp vsp/1 23*0

R2_1 vsp/2 vsp/3 30*0

R3_2 vsp/3 vsp/4 50*0

R3_2 v2 v1 50

C1 vsp/1 vsp 60

What's the regular expression for that on nedit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^(R.*\bvsp\b.*?)(\d+)$
Replace: $1$2*0
```

### Demo

On Nedit regex, you might try using the following replacement instead:

```
\1\2*0
```

Comment: Like I mentioned, it should start with 'R' as well hence fifth line can't have a replacement

Comment: @VenkatramanNatarajan Thanks for pointing this out, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't seem to select

Comment: It is working in the demo.  At this point, you really should reveal which regex language/tool you are using here.

Comment: I am using nedit. Yes it seem to work on demo. On demo, I see it removes the first character

Comment: Thanks, I see the problem is in finding. It's not able to locate.

Comment: Figured it out. ^(R.*vsp.*?)(\d+)$ this works on nedit and \1\2*0 works on nedit

Comment: Please _edit_ my answer then and add necessary details.  I know regex, but I don't know your tool.